# what is ids? retrieving YouTube Analytics data

Tags: youtube, google-analytics

I am using [YouTube's analytics explorer](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/), 
I am trying to query the service for data but I do not know how to fill out the first parameter.

The first parameter is IDS and the directions state that IDS is: Unique channel or content owner ID for retrieving YouTube Analytics data. Either `channel==C` or `contentOwner==O` where 'C' is the encrypted channel ID and 'O' is the content owner name. (string)

Where do I get either the `contentOwner` or channel?

Comment: What have you tried thus far?  Do you have any code that you could post?  Are you getting an exception?

Comment: if you follow the link and scroll down to where is says "try it" I am not sure how to fill in the field titled ids

Comment: here is what the code and the exception look like but following the link i provided the filling out the form technically does the same thing.

I am not sure what to put in the field "c == test" I don't don;t what IDS is or content owner or channel id or how to get them and that is the problem:

_analyticService.Reports.Query("c == test", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-02", "views").Fetch();

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Request parameter validation failed for [Google.Apis.Requests.Request(query @ https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?alt=json&prettyPrint=true&end-...

Comment: This seems to have been answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469216/youtube-analyticsservice-report-parameters/14470273#14470273

Comment: `channel` is indeed discussed over there, but what about  `contentOwner` ?