# youtube analyticsService Report parameters

Tags: youtube

I am authenticating with google to try and get youtube analytics my problem is that i don't know how to filled you the parameters when quering youtube
here i am making a new service: and then try to query it

I am not sure what to put in the "ids" parameter or where to find it?
What do I put there?

_analyticService = new YoutubeAnalyticsService(_authenticator = CreateAuthenticator());
...
_analyticService.Reports.Query("ids", "2013-01-01", "2013-02-02", "views").Fetch();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ids parameter is the an expression with the id of your channel. If you go to http://www.youtube.com/analytics and click on the title with your own channel name, you get a link like http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCYHMS8hN8s49F93iJuEgG6w The last part is the id of your channel. You have to use this as the ids parameter in an expression like "channel==UCYHMS8hN8s49F93iJuEgG6w". This is to query in the context of your own channel. This is needed as you might have access to several channels.

I can query views for one of my videos by: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=channel%3D%3DUCYHMS8hN8s49F93iJuEgG6w&start-date=2013-01-01&end-date=2013-02-02&metrics=views&dimensions=day&filters=video%3D%3D_iwmv6644dA&sort=day&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Try to use the API explorer at the bottom of this page, there are some text explaining the different parameters there as well. https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/

Hope it goes well!

Comment: any idea how i could get this same thing programmaticly?

Comment: It's basically just your user id, here are some more about it: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:userId To get it programatically, maybe the user profile api could help: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#User_profile_entry