# youtube analytics ids value

Tags: youtube

I am trying to use Youtube analytics but I am not sure how to fill out the parameters properly

Here is the form I am trying to fill out: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#s/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query

How do you find out the value of ids?

It states: Unique channel or content owner ID for retrieving YouTube Analytic data. Either channel==C or contentOwner==O where 'C' is the encrypted channel ID and 'O' is the content owner name. (string)

I have tried contentOwner=={myapikey}
where {myapikey} is an api key for my google app

How do I get the proper value of ids?
My goal is to execute a query on the above link.

Comment: This seems to have been answered here already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14469216/youtube-analyticsservice-report-parameters/14470273#14470273

Comment: Channels are discussed over there, but it is still not clear where to fetch `contentOwner` from. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the values for the currently logged in user that you can put into ids=channel==%here$% using an authenticated call to https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

For ids=contentOwner==%here%:
This is for the case where your user is associated to a YT content owner. Right now you would need to ask your client (a YT content owner) to get this ID. The client can get it from their partner manager.